# Action Client Results

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've been looking at action clients now for a while.  I have used these before, but never really used the results from the action servers that I've made in the past... but now I made a server that sends back results, which I get no errors from during compile time, but I haven't figured out how to use them on the client side without causing the build to fail.

```
ik_solve_msgs::IK_SolveActionResult ik_solve_results;
ik_solve_results = m_ikclient.getResult();
```

fails... I've tried as many ways as I can to see if I can get this working, but haven't had any success.

error message I'm getting,

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘ik_solve_results = actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::getResult() [with ActionSpec = ik_solve_msgs::IK_SolveAction_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::ResultConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const ik_solve_msgs::IK_SolveResult_<std::allocator<void> > >, typename ActionSpec::_action_result_type::_result_type = ik_solve_msgs::IK_SolveResult_<std::allocator<void> >]()’
```

Does anyone actually know how to get the results back and use them?

all I see in the examples only uses the results to tell if the action server has finished, which I use,

```
bool finished_before_timeout = m_ikclient.waitForResult(ros::Duration(30.0));
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63006/action-client-results/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The result is a ConstPtr.
Dereference it by putting a `*` in front of the result to use it this way.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2013-05-19**:
Thanks, that's the correct answer.  I found that getting results like this resolves my build issue, but haven't been able to test it yet since I have some other bugs to work first.
ik_solve_msgs::IK_SolveResult ik_solve_results = *m_ikclient.getResult();